# ISession.SaveOrUpdate() does not fire any event in DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener

Tags: nhibernate

I am using NH 3.2 and try to implement auto audit by creating my own class

```
Public Class AuditEventListener
    Inherits DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener

    Protected Overrides Function PerformSave(entity As Object, id As Object, persister As IEntityPersister, _
                                             useIdentityColumn As Boolean, anything As Object, source As IEventSource, _
                                             requiresImmediateIdAccess As Boolean) As Object

        Return MyBase.PerformSave(entity, id, persister, useIdentityColumn, anything, source, requiresImmediateIdAccess)
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Function PerformSaveOrUpdate([event] As SaveOrUpdateEvent) As Object
        Return MyBase.PerformSaveOrUpdate([event])
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub PerformUpdate([event] As NHibernate.Event.SaveOrUpdateEvent, entity As Object, persister As NHibernate.Persister.Entity.IEntityPersister)
        MyBase.PerformUpdate([event], entity, persister)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function EntityIsPersistent([event] As NHibernate.Event.SaveOrUpdateEvent) As Object
        Return MyBase.EntityIsPersistent([event])
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Function EntityIsTransient([event] As NHibernate.Event.SaveOrUpdateEvent) As Object
        Return MyBase.EntityIsTransient([event])
    End Function
End Class
```

And my code calls `ISession.Save()` then `PerformSaveOrUpdate`, `EntityIsTransient` and `PerformSave` are fired in sequence, which is good.

But if I call `ISession.SaveOrUpdate()` then nothing is fired.

Anything wrong which the code above?

Comment: This might be a stupid question but are you adding your event listener into the correct event listener collection when you create the sessionfactory?

Comment: I have `Dim config As FluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure()...` then `Dim nhConfig = config.BuildConfiguration()` and then `nhConfig.EventListeners.SaveEventListeners = New ISaveOrUpdateEventListener() {New AuditEventListener()}`. I guess I should have correct registration of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason, that I made s mistake. I only registered `nhConfig.EventListeners.SaveEventListeners` event but forget to register `nhConfig.EventListeners.SaveOrUpdateEventListeners` event.